# Maximum nice value for os.nice()

Tags: python, unix, code-cleanup, nice

I know that `os.nice(20)` sets the maximum nice level on linux.

But I don't know the value of other unixes (I don't care about MS-Win).

Is there somewhere a symbolic value for the maximal nice value which I can use from python?

Prefered solution:

`os.nice(NICE_MAX)`

I tried to find a solution here:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.nice
- `dir(os)`
- `grep -i nice /usr/lib64/python/os*.py`

Comment: Wikipedia says 19 or 20 is the maximum nice value. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29

Comment: @JayanthKoushik I try to avoid magic numbers in my code. And it should be portable to all unix like operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest to a standard we get here is from POSIX (IEEE 1003). The actual specification there does leave the range to the implementation, but notes:

> If value+{NZERO} is less than the system’s lowest supported nice
>   value, setpriority( ) shall set the nice value to the lowest supported
>   value; if value+{NZERO} is greater than the system’s highest supported
>   nice value, setpriority( ) shall set the nice value to the highest
>   supported value.

Thus, if you just want the highest niceness, you could pass it `INT_MAX`, but that value is not easily found in Python. `NZERO` does provide the bounds, but is likewise hard to find (it's defined in `limits.h`).

However, Python's [`os.nice`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.nice) doesn't behave like [`setpriority`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/setpriority) - it *increases* the process niceness, and also returns the resulting niceness. So if all you want to do is set the highest niceness, you could just run a while loop until `os.nice(N)` returns the same value twice, given N is any positive value that does fit in `ctypes.c_int` (any integer from 1 to 32767 is guaranteed to fit).

Answer (score 0):

From [getpriority(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpriority.2.html) notes:

> The actual priority range varies between kernel versions.  Linux
>   before 1.3.36 had -infinity..15.  Since kernel 1.3.43, Linux has the
>   range -20..19.  Within the kernel, nice values are actually
>   represented using the corresponding range 40..1 (since negative
>   numbers are error codes) and these are the values employed by the
>   setpriority() and getpriority() system calls.  The glibc wrapper
>   functions for these system calls handle the translations between the
>   user-land and kernel representations of the nice value according to
>   the formula unice = 20 - knice.